# Subtracting a number from every number in a document

Tags: replace, ms-word

I have a document with hundreds or thousands of numbers.  These are page references.  The page references have now shifted, so I need to modify every reference.

Using regex in word advanced find and replace, I have tried:

`[0-9]{1,}`

While this does return each number, it will also then return the next 2 digits of a 3 digit number, which I want to avoid.

The numbers each have 2 or 3 digits and need to subtract 14 from each.

Example:

```
George V, 116
George Washington Memorial Parkway, 223
Georgian designs, 91, 196, 202; as unique 215
```

This should become:

```
George V, 102
George Washington Memorial Parkway, 209
Georgian designs, 77, 182, 188; as unique 203
```

Comment: The pattern matches 1 or more digits. What exactly do you mean by `The numbers each have 2 or 3 digits and need to subtract 14 from each.`? You want to subtract the number 14 as in a calculation?

Comment: James: what would be most helpful is to include a few lines of sample input and corresponding lines of what you'd like to see as output.

Comment: Regex matches but doesn't do calculations.

Comment: The match is fine for now.

Comment: I'm also open to another solution, avoiding regex as I'm finding word regex to be buggy.

Comment: Um... Usually, one wouldn't "hard code" page numbers into a Word document. Better to use the "cross-reference" feature so that the page numbers will be dynamic...

Comment: That aside, as it stands the question does not appear to be about programming, so would be off-topic on Stack Overflow. And if you're asking for code, it falls under "too broad"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should find all numbers in Word:
**`<[0-9]{1,}>`**

`<` and `>` represent the start and end of words.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is to also subtract 14 from the current number...

Comment: @CindyMeister The OP said in a comment that finding the numbers will suffice.

Comment: That's great, thank you!  Does exactly what I needed.  The rest I can manage.